# QGIS Viewshed Analysis Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, viewshed

Does anyoe have a link to or know of a list of raster formats the above tool can work with? I'm on QGIS 2.8 using the latest version of the plugin.

I've tried a couple of different raster types and but have so far only had success on an .adf (ESRI grid) raster.

Answer (score 2):

See my working example here: [Performing viewshed analysis with Dutch AHN files in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153198/how-to-perform-viewshed-analysis-with-dutch-ahn-files).

It works for me with SRTM files the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Ive just used ASTER generated satellite imagery (as a tif) and it worked fine. I found the trick was to only have the salient laters switched on. Hope that helps